# Xamarin.Forms fontawesome works on UWP but shows square on Android

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I have added fontawesome in my projects of Xamarin.Forms, on UWP font looks as expected but on android it is square. I have set build-action to AndroidAsset but it does not work.

Comment: Have you replace the font with FontAwesome when there is one character in the text field and if that character has the value of 0xf000 or higher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android, it's a bit of a hassle use `FontAwesome`. This code behind post is about how to use Font Awesome in the simplest way possible. It's as easy as using a Label once set up.

We use a custom renderer that looks at the Label in question, determines if there is one character in the text field and if that character has the value of `0xf000` or higher. If so, we replace the font with `FontAwesome`.

Since the icons all begin at `0xf000` or higher, the custom renderer will make sure that the correct font is used

[*Reference article*](http://www.johankarlsson.net/2015/09/fontawesome-using-xamarin-forms-and.html)

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(AwesomeRenderer))]

namespace Awesome.Droid
{
    public class AwesomeRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var label = (TextView)Control;

            var text = label.Text;
            if(text.Length > 1 || text[0] < 0xf000)
            {
                return;
            }

            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.Assets, "fontawesome.ttf");
            label.Typeface = font;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! Hopefully it doesnt need renderer on UWP. Soon I will have to deploy it on iOS as well, maybe you know if iOS needs custom view renderer as well?